Starcraft 2: How to beat 3 "Harder" AI
As a Terran I am trying to get an achievements on SC2 and I just can't get it -- how do I win a game vs 3 "harder" ai. I can beat elite and insane ai 1-on-1 and I am aware of tricks such as liberators (ai can't counter them correctly).
Things I've tried:

Using a 2 v 2 map and trying to clear out the first "neighbour" ai fast and then defending the bottleneck with PFs

Using much larger (8x) maps to macro



Question:

Which map would be a good map to be able to bottleneck the enemy while not denying myself too many resources?

ANY help on this appreciated. I'm Plat level on the ladder.

I believe a while ago there was a trend in the youtube scene to fight vs the maximum number of hardest-difficulty AI, and yeah; the trend seemed to be abusing liberators for harass and using tank positions to obliterate the attacks they send. IIRC one strategy was also to repeatedly trigger their 'my base is under attack, send everything you can to defend it' behaviour and then instead of massing up a big army they would send a trickle of units into the meat grinder as soon as they spawned. one example of a successful run here.

@Kaia yeah that was promoted by uthermal. But I have known for a long time that liberators are not correctly programmed into the ai; it can't deal with them correctly.

After a week of frustration, then right after writing this post, I then proceeded to actually achieve this.
The way I did it:

fight against Zerg.
Arkadia map because it has a single enterance to all three opponent bases. (3vs3)
Use Liberators early to stymie their base. and catch all troops / drones moving out onto the map.

